# Config maven setting in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

My project has 3 maven module and they are built by nodejs script.

Now I want to integrate with Jenkin and Nexus. My Jenkin build config look like this:

[image: Build config]I also add my maven `settings.xml` in **Provide configuration files** build step in **Build** section but it didn't work. Maven still fail and could not resolve dependencies in my Nexus repo.

In my local maven `settings.xml` I have added some config for Nexus repository and another repository.

Can you enlight me this case. I'm new to Jenkin.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just find a way to work around by adding `mvn-settings.xml` directly to my folder and edit the run command like:

```
mvn clean install -s mvn-settings.xml
```

Comment: Primary reason not to do this: settings.xml might contain passwords which should not be in your repository.

Comment: You could use a Jenkins Credential Plugin secret file to mitigate the risk

Answer (score 11):

I came up with a solution combining the question and answer(both from Anh). The problem with Anh's solution to the problem was that we had to include the settings.xml which might contain credentials(in my case, it had some confidential information), which shouldn't be a part of repository(as highlighted in the comment by sigi).

This is how I avoided that risk(Step by step):

1. From Jenkins home, goto Manage **Jenkins > Managed Files**
2. Click on **Add a new Config > Maven settings.xml > Keep the ID unedited(preferably) > Submit**
3. Provide a name for easy recognition and comment if necessary, then copy paste the xml content to the content area. Click on Submit. [image: Adding configuration XML]
4. Goto your project's build configuration, under **Build Environment** section, check **Provide Configuration files** option.
5. From the file dropdown, choose the file you added in step 3 above.
6. Now the key points is to fill in the Target field. Provide a file name(or path relative to your project if you need it like that). You can also optionally fill in a variable name if you need the configuration to be used in other parts of the build configuration(These come from the Config file provider plugin). [image: Provide configuration files]
7. Now in the Build section, provide the following command to take the settings.xml file from the checked out projects path(which jenkins copied there for you to use):
   `clean install -s settings.xml`

Please note that the build project I created in Jenkins was as a Maven Project.

Answer (score 5):

There is another way:

1. which is an extension to `@Anh N. Nguyen` answer but taking care of not storing secrets in source control.
2. which is simpler than `@Harikrishnan`, fewer in steps and don't require any additional plugin ([config-file-provider](https://plugins.jenkins.io/config-file-provider/))

**Steps:**

1. Configure `mvn-settings.xml` to read secrets from the environment variables.

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <username>${env.NEXUS_USER}</username>
      <password>${env.NEXUS_PASSWORD}</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

2. You can now check-in this in your source control, totally safe.
3. Expose your Jenkins credentials secrets in the job environment variable (Syntax for declarative pipeline)

```
pipeline {
  agent {...}
  environment {
    NEXUS_CREDS = credentials('NexusArtifactoryLogin')
    NEXUS_USER = "$NEXUS_CREDS_USR"
    NEXUS_PASSWORD = "$NEXUS_CREDS_PSW"
  }
  stages {
    ...
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
          \\assuming mvn-settings.xml is at root/current folder, otherwise provide absolute or relative path
          sh 'mvn -s mvn-settings.xml clean install'
      }
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This approach is really simple and nice to use in Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: This is a simpler and more secure solution. Worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> I also add my maven settings.xml in Provide configuration files

Wait... you never have to do that: Any maven command would look for the settings.xml file in `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml`: you only need to make sure the user running the Jenkins slave (where the job is actually executed) does has that file in that specific folder.
Then make sure the user can use `mvn clean install` on a local maven project first. Once that is working, you can try your Jenkins build.

Comment: Maven run successfully in local and the content of maven setting in Jenkin is the same with local setting.

Comment: Make sure the Jenkins slave is using the same account as the one you are using when testing the maven command.

Comment: I don't get your point. Right now I'm building manually by clicking the `Build Now` link

Comment: @AnhN.Nguyen check the user actually runnnig the job: in your job result page, click on "Environment variable" and check USERNAME or HOME to see if the job is actually running with the same user as the one used to test maven locally.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Go to your JOB configuration

than to the Build section

Add build step :- Invoke top level maven target and fill Maven version and Goal

than click on Advance button and mention **settings** file path as mention in image

Answer (score 1):

just put your settings.xml file in your code base and
run mvn clean install -s <setting.xml_file_path>

Answer (score 1):

run your job with mvn -X command . in logs you will find from where jenkins is picking the setting.xml file .

in my cases i had placed my settings.file in /.m2/ but on checking the logs it was found below : /var/lib/jenkins/.m2

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a procedure described [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017812931-Best-Practices-for-managing-Maven-configurations-in-Jenkins).  For a Maven build job,

1. Use Manage Jenkins/Manage Credentials to add a username/password credential for your remote repo.
2. Use Manage Jenkins/Managed Files to add a new Maven settings file.  Copy the content of your settings.xml.  Leave out the `<servers>` section, but reference the remote repo server id and URL in a `<profile>`.  Also add the remote repo id and select the credentials by name from the popup menu in the Managed Files wizard.
3. For your Maven job, under Configure/Build/Advanced.../Settings File/Provided settings.xml, select your managed settings file by name from the popup menu.

When you trigger a build, Jenkins will inject a `<server>` element with your credentials into a temporary settings file.