# Maven project Jenkins compile error: error: packages org.apache.commons does not exist

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Getting error like below:

Jenkins compile error

> [javac]
>   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CWL_Smoke_New/SeleniumFW/CWL_NewSuite/src/com/collegeweeklive/common/AppLibrary.java:14:
>   error: package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist
>
> [javac] import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

like this I am getting 100 such error and also some error saying "cannot find symbol"

**Note: When I clean, build or install on local at that time all looks good and Build is Successful**

Screenshot of error window:

[image: https://www.screencast.com/t/7cuoaO0l4uZ]

I have all the dependency in pom.xml

Please help to resolve

Comment: What is the `scope` of the `commons-lang3` library in `pom.xml`?

Comment: nothing specific to commons I'm getting error even for package org.openqa.selenium

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be an issue with jenkins configuration. Below post may answer your problem
[Config maven setting in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43796428/config-maven-setting-in-jenkins)