# Not able to upload artifacts to Nexus from the same machine using mvn clean deploy, works fine from my local Windows 10 machine

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jenkins, nexus

**Java 11**

I have a very basic `Spring Boot` application that I would like to build and deploy the artifacts on a `Nexus` sever.

**mvn clean deploy (from my local Win 10 machine - WORKS !!!)**

**mvn clean deploy (from Nexus machine - FAILS ????)**

**mvn clean deploy (from Jenkins - FAILS ????)**

When I run `mvn clean deploy` command from my local `Win 10` machine all the artifacts get deployed successfully on remote `Nexus` server and I can even see and browse them.

But when I clone the project and run `mvn clean deploy` on the very same machine where both `Nexus` and `Jenkins` (`Ubuntu` box) are installed it gives me `Not authorized` error.

I have already copied over BOTH `settings.xml` and `settings-security.xml` from my local `Windows` machine to `Ubuntu` (`~/.m2`) where `Nexus` is installed.

I have disabled the `firewalls` as well just to be sure that no ports are blocked.

I am confused how the artifacts are getting copied over from a remote machine but not from the same machine.

**pom.xml**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <addResources>true</addResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>my-maven-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://my-nexus-server/nexus/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>my-maven-releases</id>
        <url>http://my-nexus-server/nexus/repository/maven-releases/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://johndoe@bitbucket.org/johndoe/todo.git</connection>
    <url>https://johndoe@bitbucket.org/johndoe/todo</url>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://johndoe@bitbucket.org/johndoe/todo.git</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

**Error (Nexus is installed on this machine):**

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ todo ---
[INFO] Installing /home/admin/cloned-apps/todo/pom.xml to /home/admin/.m2/repository/com/example/todo/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/todo-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ todo ---
Downloading from my-maven-snapshots: http://my-nexus-server/nexus/repository/maven-snapshots/com/example/todo/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.example:todo:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to my-maven-snapshots (http://my-nexus-server/nexus/repository/maven-snapshots/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for todo 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] todo ............................................... FAILURE [  4.622 s]
[INFO] todo-webapp ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.973 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-16T02:39:48Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project todo: Failed to retrieve remote metadata com.example:todo:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT        /maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata com.example:todo:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to my-maven-snapshots (http://my-nexus-server/nexus/repository/maven-snapshots/        ): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: You are not authorized which means the credentials are not correctly configured in Jenkins (should be done via credentials storage and the config file provider plugins which handles the part with settings.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

> mvn clean deploy (from Nexus machine - FAILS ????)

Are you sure you're running `mvn clean deploy` from the same user under whose `$HOME/.m2` directory you've copied the `settings.xml` and `settings-security.xml` files?

Also, did you try adding the password directly to `settings.xml` to rule out issues (if any) with `settings-security.xml`?

P.S: Avoid running `mvn` commands with `sudo` privilege.

Comment: Yes @kayvis, because I am the sole user, there is no one else. However I figured out one of the mistake that I did in settings.xml and settings-security.xml. I copied both these files under maven home directory instead of ~/.m2 directory. Now I am able to built it from Nexus machine. The only thing that's not working is through Jenkins now.

Comment: @Nital, you'd have to setup maven configuration in Jenkins so that you can tell which settings to use while running the build. You can refer here: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017812931-Best-Practices-for-managing-Maven-configurations-in-Jenkins and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43796428/config-maven-setting-in-jenkins

Comment: ...This is because Jenkins would clean the workspace (including deleting the ~/.m2 directory) for every run as it would run the maven build from a different machine every time. Jenkins hosted by organisations would have a pool of machines from which a random machine would be picked and the build would be run from that. Also, different teams might want to use different artifactory from which they might want to download their dependencies.

Comment: I already have that in place. I also tried to specify the settings.xml file manually using -s parameter while running the `mvn clean deploy` command

Comment: However I am leaning towards pipelines now as this is gaining more traction now in future versions.