# How to import a jar file from jfrog artifactory into Jenkins .m2 repository?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I have a Jfrog Artifactory installation which has some artifacts. I want to pull these artifacts onto my Jenkins .m2 repository. I don't have much knowledge of Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have properly configured you [maven remote repository settings](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html), maven will resolve the artifacts and place them in the local repo during the build process.

Alternatively, (not recommended), you can use curl or wget and [`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> ...`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) , but that is rather pointless and more work than letting maven do what maven does.

Cloudbees has [recommendations for settings](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017812931-Best-Practices-for-managing-Maven-configurations-in-Jenkins) if you don't want them in you repo's settings.xml; [S/O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43796428/598141) has some advice, as does the [pipeline-maven plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-maven/) and the [Jenkins Docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-maven/).